# Tensorflow: how to swap variables between scopes and set variables in scope from another

Tags: python, scope, tensorflow

I have different scopes and they have variables with same names but with different values. I want to swap values of these variables between scopes.
Example:

```
with tf.variable_scope('sc1'):
   a1 = tf.Variable(0, name='test_var1')
   b1 = tf.Variable(1, name='test_var2')
with tf.variable_scope('sc2'):
   a2 = tf.Variable(2, name='test_var1')
   b2 = tf.Variable(3, name='test_var2')
```

I want to set `a2` to 0, `b2` to 1, `a1` to 2 and `b1` to 3.

I was thinking about getting needed variables with `tf.get_collection_ref` but I can't see how I can change scope of the variable, so probably I need to change values of variables. In this case I need to store one value in temporary variable and then remove that temporary variable. 
I don't sure that it will work and this seems too complicated.
Is there simple way to do it?

**UPD1:** Also I need to set all variables in one collection from another collection. I think that it's similar issue. 
For example in code above set `a2` equal to 0 and `b2` to 1.

**UPD2:** This code doesn't work:

```
with tf.variable_scope('sc1'):
    a1 = tf.get_variable(name='test_var1', initializer=0.)
    b1 = tf.Variable(0, name='test_var2')

with tf.variable_scope('sc2'):
    a2 = tf.get_variable(name='test_var1', initializer=1.)
    b2 = tf.Variable(1, name='test_var2')


def swap_tf_scopes(col1, col2):
    col1_dict = {}
    col2_dict = {}
    for curr_var in col1:
        curr_var_name = curr_var.name.split('/')[-1]
        col1_dict[curr_var_name] = curr_var

    for curr_var in col2:
        curr_var_name = curr_var.name.split('/')[-1]
        curr_col1_var = col1_dict[curr_var_name]
        tmp_t = tf.identity(curr_col1_var)
        assign1 = curr_col1_var.assign(curr_var)
        assign2 = curr_var.assign(tmp_t)
    return [assign1, assign2]


col1 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='sc1')
col2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='sc2')

tf_ops_t = swap_tf_collections(col1, col2)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(tf_ops_t)
print sess.run(col1) #prints [0.0, 1] but I expect [1.0, 1]
print sess.run(col2) #prints [1.0, 1] but I expect [0.0, 0]
```

Comment: One guess, based on a quick read: the write to one Variable is overwriting the input to the other write. `tf.identity` isn't enough to force a copy of the Tensor data. Try something like `tmp_t = curr_col1_var + 0.0`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I want to swap relatively small scopes, so it's not a problem have temporary scope for swapping. I made working prototype. It doesn't look cool and actually ugly but works.

```
def swap_tf_collections(col1, col2, tmp_col):
    col2_dict = {}
    for i in xrange(len(col1)):
        curr_var_name = col2[i].name.split('/')[-1]
        col2_dict[curr_var_name] = col2[i]

    col1_dict = {}
    for i in xrange(len(col1)):
        curr_var_name = col1[i].name.split('/')[-1]
        col1_dict[curr_var_name] = col1[i]

    # set values from second scope to tmp_dict 
    tmp_dict = {}
    assigns_arr = []
    for i in xrange(len(tmp_col)):
        curr_var_name = tmp_col[i].name.split('/')[-1]
        tmp_dict[curr_var_name] = tmp_col[i]
        assign0 = tmp_dict[curr_var_name].assign(col2_dict[curr_var_name])
        assigns_arr.append(assign0)

    for i in xrange(len(col2)):
        curr_var_name = col2[i].name.split('/')[-1]
        curr_col1_var = col1_dict[curr_var_name]
        tmp_t = tmp_dict[curr_var_name]
        with tf.control_dependencies(assigns_arr):
            assign1 = col2[i].assign(curr_col1_var)
            assigns_arr.append(assign1)
            with tf.control_dependencies(assigns_arr):
                assign2 = curr_col1_var.assign(tmp_t)
                assigns_arr.append(assign2)
    return assigns_arr



# first scope
with tf.variable_scope('sc1'):
    a1 = tf.get_variable(name='test_var1', initializer=0.)
    b1 = tf.Variable(0, name='test_var2')
# second scope    
with tf.variable_scope('sc2'):
    a2 = tf.get_variable(name='test_var1', initializer=1.)
    b2 = tf.Variable(1, name='test_var2')

# getting them as collections
col1 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='sc1')
col2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='sc2')

# creating temporary scope. It MUST have same variables names as our scopes but it doesn't have to have same data as second scope
with tf.variable_scope('tmp_scope_for_scopes_swap'):
    for i in xrange(len(col2)):
        col2_var = col2[i]
        col2_var_name = col2[i].name.split('/')[-1].split(':')[0]
        var = tf.Variable(col2_var.initialized_value(), name=col2_var_name)
        tmp_col.append(var)

# exec
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    tf_ops_t = swap_tf_collections(col1, col2, tmp_col) 
    sess.run(tf_ops_t)  # swap will not work without this line

col1_dict = {i.name:i for i in col1}
col2_dict = {i.name:i for i in col2}
print sess.run(col1_dict)
print sess.run(col2_dict)
```

Note that I use dependency control! Without it function results will be undefined.

Also despite that function name is `swap_tf_collections` I think that it will not work for arbitrary collections (to be fair I doubt even about scopes).

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.variable_scope('sc1'):
    a1 = tf.get_variable(name='test_var1', initializer=0.)
    b1 = tf.Variable(0, name='test_var2')

with tf.variable_scope('sc2'):
    a2 = tf.get_variable(name='test_var1', initializer=1.)
    b2 = tf.Variable(1, name='test_var2')


def swap_tf_scopes(col1, col2):
    col1_dict = {}
    for curr_var in col1:
        curr_var_name = curr_var.name.split('/')[-1]
        col1_dict[curr_var_name] = curr_var
    for curr_var in col2:
        curr_var_name = curr_var.name.split('/')[-1]
        curr_col1_var = col1_dict[curr_var_name]
        tmp_t =tf.Variable(curr_col1_var.initialized_value()) 
        sess.run(tmp_t.initializer)
        sess.run(tf.assign(curr_col1_var,curr_var))
        sess.run(tf.assign(curr_var,tmp_t))

col1 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='sc1')
col2 = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='sc2')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
swap_tf_scopes(col1, col2)
print(sess.run(col1)) 
print(sess.run(col2))
```

Hello！Try this one. I guess it will work.