# Tensorflow: how to assign variables properly

Tags: variables, tensorflow

It's not duplicate of [How to assign value to a tensorflow variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220532/how-to-assign-value-to-a-tensorflow-variable)

I was trying to do simpliest thing: just swap variables [Tensorflow: how to swap variables between scopes and set variables in scope from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41949633/tensorflow-how-to-swap-variables-between-scopes-and-set-variables-in-scope-from),
 and I still can't do it.

BUT now I know that `assign` changes even copy of tensor which I get with `tf.identity`. I don't want this. I need copy of variable for swapping.

```
In [10]: a = tf.Variable(1)

In [11]: b = tf.identity(a)

In [12]: a += 1

In [14]: sess.run(a)
Out[14]: 2

In [15]: sess.run(b)
Out[15]: 1

In [16]: a = tf.Variable(1)

In [17]: b = tf.identity(a)

In [18]: assign_t = a.assign(2)

In [20]: sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

In [21]: sess.run(a)
Out[21]: 1

In [22]: sess.run(assign_t)
Out[22]: 2

In [23]: sess.run(a)
Out[23]: 2

In [24]: sess.run(b)
Out[24]: 2
```

How can I assign value to `a` without changing `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tf.identity()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#identity) operation is stateless. When you have a `tf.Variable` called `a`, the value of `tf.identity(a)` will always be the same as the value of `a`. If you want `b` to remember a previous value of `a`, you should create `b` as a `tf.Variable` as well:

```
a = tf.Variable(1)
b = tf.Variable(a.initialized_value())

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Initially, variables `a` and `b` have the same value.
print(sess.run([a, b])) ==> [1, 1]

# Update the value of `a` to 2.
assign_op = a.assign(2)
sess.run(assign_op)

# Now, `a` and `b` have different values.
print(sess.run([a, b])) ==> [2, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! But what about first case, when `a+=1` not equal to `identity(a)`?

Comment: Oh, I see: `a+=1` make another tensor with different name.

Comment: That's right. `a += 1` is equivalent to `new_a = a + 1; a = new_a`, which just updates the Python binding for `a` (and not the value in the `tf.Variable`).